# Visual Studio skipping if statements?

Tags: c++

The program outputs a certain pattern when I output a certain number. I haven't included the libraries and the int main or the prompt, but this is the part of the code I'm having trouble with.

When I'm inputing 5 for instance, I am supposed to get:

```
111111111
122222221
123333321
123444321
123454321
```

What I am getting instead is:

```
111111111
2222222
33333
444
5
```

I wrote the first if statement

```
if (lb2 < lb1){}
```

to insert the 1s and 2s before it, but it seems like it is getting skipped. Can anybody tell me why?

```
int lb1, lb2, lb3; 
cout << endl << "LETTER BOX:" << endl;
for (lb1 = 1; lb1 <= number; lb1++) {

    cout << "   ";

    for (lb2 = 1; lb2 = (2*number)-1 ; lb2++){
        lb3 = 1;

        if (lb2 < lb1){
            do {
                cout << lb2;
                lb3++;
            } while (lb3 < lb1);
            break;
        }
        else if (lb2 = lb1){                
            do {
                cout << lb2;
                lb3++;
            } while (lb3 <= ((2*number)-1)-(2*(lb2-1)));
            break;
        } 
        else if (lb2 > lb1){                
            do {
                cout << lb2;
                lb3++;
            } while (lb3 <= ((2*number)-1)-(2*(lb2-1)));
            break;
        } 
    }  

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I see a couple instances of confusing assignment `=` with equality comparison `==`

Comment: did you mean `lb2 == (2*number)-1`

Comment: Also, `lb2 = lb1` should be `lb2 == lb1`.

Comment: The output is actually empty when I type that instead, strangely. 5 blank lines :(

Comment: Use = whenever you mean in english "is now" and use == for "is?"

Comment: fix all the places you have = instead of == and then run the program under the debugger and step through it

Comment: How do I step through it?

The output is actually empty when I type that instead, strangely. 5 blank lines :(

Comment: You say you use MSVisual. Here's how to fix these problems faster (better in the long run). Click on a margin near the line number somewhere which should place a little red dot. Then go to Debug->Start debugging. When the program hits that line, hit step-over. Do this and use watches to find your errors. It is better to learn how to find and fix mistakes through debug mode than think through it by hand.

Comment: or just start the program with F10 (step into), keep pressing F10 or F11

Comment: How do i know where to place the red fot? Also, step-over is f9 right?

Comment: Red dot is just where the break will start. It runs like normal until it hits the red dot, and from there you'll go line by line.  If the error only comes in a particular region of the function place it there. You can place it at the start  like 5 lines in and keep stepping over using fn + F11 i believe. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
for (lb2 = 1; lb2 = (2*number)-1 ; lb2++){
```

the condition statement uses = instead of <= which messes up the value in lb2

```
else if (lb2 = lb1){
```

again, using = instead of == changes the value in lb2 instead of just checking it.

Also, as I understand from your code, the lb1 loop controls lines whereas lb2 loop controls numbers in a line. However, the three break statements at the end of each condition prevents lb2 loop to iterate (2*number) -1 times.

Another thing is, the three do-while loops dont't increment lb2, which causes lines to have more than (2*number) -1 numbers.

Comment: "Another thing is, the three do-while loops dont't increment lb2, which causes lines to have more than (2*number) -1 numbers"

This seems to be my problem, based on my debugger!! Can you possible elborate how to make the lb2 reset to 1??

Comment: For number = 5, you want 9 numbers per line. The lb2 loop controls that. However, in do-while loops you print multiple numbers while not incrementing lb2, which means 9+ numbers per line. You can add a lb2++ inside the do-while loops. This way, if the do-while loop prints let's say 5 numbers, lb2 will increase by 5 and guarantee that every line has 9 numbers. However, you use lb2 in the cout and loop control statements. You should think about how to handle these if you decide to increment lb2.

Answer (score 0):

your do {} while () controls everything, making the for(lb2) loop and most of the if-else case useless, that's why it's printing the same thing until the while loop breaks.

Also break statements break out of the loop so don't use break if you know you want to quit. 
Lastly, you're print nothing after changing from = to == because lb2 starts at 1, so 1 == 9 always fail. Change it to <= 2*number-1 just like the first loop.

So stepping through: 
for first row, lb1 = 1, lb2 = 1: if (lb2 == lb1) case is run. The while loop for if case says:

```
do { cout << lb2; lb3++; } while (lb3 < 9); //lb2 is always 1
// break out of lb2 loop, now lb1 = 2
```

for 2nd-5th row: lb1 = 2 (3,4,5....), lb2 = 1: if (lb2 > lb1) case is always chosen:

```
do { cout << lb2; lb3++ } while (lb3 < (9 - 2)); //lb2 is always 2
```

You should learn loop first. http://www.codecademy.com is a good place to start, but I don't think they have c++ though. However, other languages are just the same (Ruby, Java, Javascript). Here's an example, try to follow it.

```
 // loop 1: for row from 1 to 5
 for (lb1 = 1; lb1 <= number; lb1++) {

    cout << "   ";
    lb3 = 1;

    // loop 2: for column from 1 to 9
    for (lb2 = 1; lb2 <= (2*number)-1 ; lb2++){

        if (lb2 < lb1){
            cout << lb3++;
        }
        else if (lb2 >= lb1 && lb2 <= 2*number - lb1){                
            cout << lb3;
        } 
        else if (lb2 > number){ 
            if (lb3 > 1) { lb3--; }               
            cout << lb3;
        } 
    }  

    cout << endl;
}
```